git GitHub remote branch push cannot be resolved to branch
Trying to push to a GitHub Repository, to a branch named Kedabra, did init checkout clone fetch add . and when I push y get the error "Kedabra cannot be resolved to branch".
git remote add origin https:
git clone https:
git fetch --all
git checkout Kedabra
git add .
git push origin Kedabra
I'm aware of the upper case lower case sensitivity
I already tried other StackOverflow questions and did not work.

Is there a commit in there between git add and git push?

You don't need to perform a git init before doing a git clone. A clone is done on "something" that is already a repository. When you perform a git clone, you're cloning a repository with its history of changes, you're not just getting a bunch of files.

Clones a repository into a newly created directory, creates remote-tracking branches for each branch in the cloned repository (visible using git branch --remotes), and creates and checks out an initial branch that is forked from the cloned repository’s currently active branch.

You either create an empty new repo, add a remote and pull its changes
git init
git remote add origin <URL>
git pull origin

or simply perform a clone
git clone <URL>

Once you've cloned your repository, or created a new one with all the remote's changes, you can perform your modifications, stage them, record them with a commit, and finally push them to your remote.
#checking-out the local kedabra branch
git checkout kedabra

#performing some changes...
## Heading #### Heading ##
#staging those changes
git add file1 file2 ... fileN

#recording the changes with a commit
git commit -m "my changes"

#pushing those changes to the remote's branch kedabra
#the -u option "binds" the local branch kedabra to the remote's branch kedabra,
#so that when the local branch kedabra is checked-out, future push and pull operations 
#will implicitly happen with the corresponding remote's branch
git push -u origin kedabra


Answer to question in the comments
In Git, refs (branches, tags, etc.) were supposed to be case-sensitive. This does work on Linux platforms. However, it fails on Windows machines. This is because a ref is physically implemented in the object store as a file with the SHA1 of the commit it's pointing to. So, since paths are treated case-insensitively on Windows, when you create a new branch with git branch FEATURE/kedabra, you're actually creating a file named kedabra under refs/heads/FEATURE/, and only on Windows, you can switch to it with git checkout FEATURE/kedabra, git checkout feature/kedabra, or any other case combination. However, this is not always true on other platforms and that's where problems arise.
If you want to rename a branch, do not tinker with the content of the object store, but instead use the provided commands. These are Git's interface and the best way to interact with it. Editing the content of the object store means changing its internal data, which requires a deep knowledge of how Git works. You can use git branch with the -m option to rename a branch.

Move/rename a branch, together with its config and reflog.

Since, you might be performing this on Windows, you cannot just resolve it with a single git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>, but with a couple of them, since new_name will simply be the lower case version of old_name, and since we've said that Windows is not case-sensitive, it would tell you that new_name already exists.
#change FEATURE/kedabra to a temporary name
git branch -m FEATURE/kedabra my_temp_branch

#set the name all in lower-case
git branch -m my_temp_branch feature/kedabra

Also, because a copy of your repository is on a remote and worked on by other developers, after renaming your local branch, you should warn your colleagues to stop working on FEATURE/kedabra and do the following:

Delete the branch FEATURE/kedabra on the remote.

git push <remote> --delete FEATURE/kedabra


Push your newly renamed branch feature/kedabra on the remote.

# while feature/kedabra is checked-out, launch a git push with the -u option.
# The -u option makes your local branch feature/kedabra track the remote's branch feature/kedabra
git push -u <remote> feature/kedabra


Tell your colleagues to rename their local branch FEATURE/kedabra in feature/kedabra as you've done earlier.

#change FEATURE/name to a temporary name
git branch -m FEATURE/kedabra my_temp_branch

#set the name all in lower-case
git branch -m my_temp_branch feature/kedabra


Tell your colleagues to update the upstream for the newly renamed branch

git branch feature/kedabra --set-upstream-to=<remote>/feature/kedabra

Lastly, I'm addressing the last question in the comments. The folder .git is a hidden folder, and it corresponds to Git's object store. In order to see it, you need to tell Windows to show hidden elements (just open an explorer window and go to View > Hidden Elements). Your FEATURE/kedabra branch will be a file named kedabra under refs/heads/FEATURE/. This is because Git uses the slash to create a directory hierarchical structure.

Thank you for your answer, the thing is that im not trying to update the files, im trying to add new independent folders.

Git tracks changes, so if you want to add folders to your repository they must contain files. Once they have some content, you can stage them in the same way you would stage a file git add myFolder/. Instead, if by independent folders you mean that you need to add some folders but you don't want Git to track them, then add their path to the gitignore. The gitignore is a configuration file that allows you to ignore certain files or paths within your working directory. Once you've given more clarifications on what you need, I can update my answer.

im trying to upload a folder but with files, now im thinking i didnt try like I should another answer on github.
this is the answer of the other question:
889
I was having this issue as well, and it was driving me crazy. I had something like feature/name but git branch -a showed me FEATURE/name. Renaming the branch, deleting and recreating it, nothing worked. What finally fixed it:
Go into .git/refs/heads
You'll see a FEATURE folder. Rename it to feature.
Can you tell me where to find this path? ".git/refs/heads"

@Kedabra I've updated my post to expand the explanation and answer the question in the comments "where to find .git/refs/heads/". Let me know if something is still unclear or if it answers your question.
